# 4 PK's as FK's into 1 column in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, foreign-keys

I've been having problems with this for a while, I have different staff roles, in different tables, that all need to be assigned to an office but cant for the life of me find an answer, any help would be appreciated. below is a code sample and an ERD of what im trying to achieve

```
CREATE TABLE office (                                    --7 
     office_id      Number(4)NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     address        address,



CREATE TABLE office_staff (                              --8 
         staff_id      Number(4)NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
         office_id            Number(4),
         manager              char(1), 
         CONSTRAINT manager_boolean CHECK (manager IN ('1','0')));

CREATE TABLE staff_role (
         staff_role_id  NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
         staff_id       tinyint references office_staff(staff_id),
         unique(staff_role_id, staff_id),
         role_name      varchar2(20));

CREATE TABLE manager (                                   --1
         manager_id        Number(4)NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
         staff_role_id as cast(1 as tinyint) persisted,
    foreign key (manager_id, staff_id) references staff_role(staff_role_id, staff_id)
         manager_firstname varchar2(20),
         manager_lastname  varchar2(20),
         gender            varchar2(1),
         date_of_birth     date,
         telephone         varchar2(11));

CREATE TABLE senior_instructor (                         --2
         senior_instructor_id   Number(4)NOT NULL,
         staff_role_id as cast(2 as tinyint) persisted,
    foreign key (senior_instructor_id, staff_id) references staff_role(staff_role_id, staff_id)
         s_instructor_firstname varchar2(20),
         s_instructor_lastname  varchar2(20),
         gender                 varchar2(1),
         date_of_birth          date,
         telephone              varchar2(11));

CREATE TABLE office_admin (                              --3
         admin_id        Number(4)NOT NULL,
         staff_role_id as cast(3 as tinyint) persisted,
    foreign key (admin_id, staff_id) references staff_role(staff_role_id, staff_id)
         admin_firstname varchar2(20),
         admin_lastname  varchar2(20),
         gender          varchar2(1),
         date_of_birth   date,
         telephone       varchar2(11));

CREATE TABLE instructor (                                --6
         instructor_id        Number(4)NOT NULL,
         staff_role_id as cast(4 as tinyint) persisted,
    foreign key (instructor_id, staff_id) references staff_role(staff_role_id, staff_id)
         instructor_firstname varchar2(20),
         instructor_lastname  varchar2(20),
         gender               varchar2(1),
         date_of_birth        date,
         telephone            varchar2(11),
         car_id               Number(4));
```

Current output reads Datatype not supported

[ERD link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHWkB.jpg)

Comment: I am not sure what is above, but for sure it is not correct Oracle SQL. So what RDBMS are you using ?

Comment: I am using Oracle 10g

Comment: Ok, so this is definitely not an Oracle syntax. There is no tinyint in Oracle (there is in MS SqlServer), this : staff_role_id as cast(1 as tinyint) persisted, is not correct syntax for oracle,  unique(staff_role_id, staff_id) also not correct - in oracle it should be:  CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (uc_col1, uc_col2, ... uc_col_n). You need to fix a lot.

Comment: I couldnt find the answer through oracle and find this SQL code to see if i can use it to get closer to an answer, as you can see its not worked

Comment: This design makes no sense -- what exactly does staff_roles table contain?  It looks like it is pairing of staff_ids and staff_roles? if this is the case then you only need to store the staff_role_id in the various role tables.  To then change the name in those tables is just strange -- use the same name (for example staff_role_id instead of instructor_id)

Comment: Basically i want to add the 4 types of staff(admin,instructor,manager and senior instructor) into the table office_staff but have all of them under staff and a staff role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed some syntax errors and changed some of the column names.

Does this code give you what you need?

```
CREATE TABLE office (                                    
     office_id      Number(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     address        VARCHAR2(200));

CREATE TABLE office_staff (                              
         staff_id      Number(4)NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
         office_id            Number(4),
         manager              char(1), 
         CONSTRAINT manager_boolean CHECK (manager IN ('1','0')));

CREATE TABLE staff_role (
         staff_role_id  NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
         staff_id       Number(4) references office_staff(staff_id),
         unique(staff_role_id, staff_id),
         role_name      varchar2(20));

CREATE TABLE manager (                                   
         manager_id        Number(4)NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
         staff_role_id NUMBER(1),
    foreign key (staff_role_id, manager_id) references staff_role(staff_role_id, staff_id),
         manager_firstname varchar2(20),
         manager_lastname  varchar2(20),
         gender            varchar2(1),
         date_of_birth     date,
         telephone         varchar2(11));

CREATE TABLE senior_instructor (                         
         senior_instructor_id   Number(4)NOT NULL,
         staff_role_id NUMBER(1),
    foreign key (staff_role_id, senior_instructor_id) references staff_role(staff_role_id, staff_id),
         s_instructor_firstname varchar2(20),
         s_instructor_lastname  varchar2(20),
         gender                 varchar2(1),
         date_of_birth          date,
         telephone              varchar2(11));

CREATE TABLE office_admin (                              
         admin_id        Number(4)NOT NULL,
         staff_role_id NUMBER(1),
    foreign key (staff_role_id, admin_id) references staff_role(staff_role_id, staff_id),
         admin_firstname varchar2(20),
         admin_lastname  varchar2(20),
         gender          varchar2(1),
         date_of_birth   date,
         telephone       varchar2(11));

CREATE TABLE instructor (                                
         instructor_id        Number(4)NOT NULL,
         staff_role_id NUMBER(1),
    foreign key (staff_role_id, instructor_id) references staff_role(staff_role_id, staff_id),
         instructor_firstname varchar2(20),
         instructor_lastname  varchar2(20),
         gender               varchar2(1),
         date_of_birth        date,
         telephone            varchar2(11),
         car_id               Number(4));
```

Is there a reason you're using 4 tables for different type of staff? If you're not required to do that, I would recommend combining them into a single table (perhaps that's what you're trying to do with office_staff) and have a relationship to the staff_roles table.

Comment: Thank you, different staff roles have different relationships to other table so wanted them separate for easier reference